# How were chi-squared levels calculated in Feller's Vol 1, VI.7 Table 5?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

Here is the table from *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*:
[image]

I tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11408357/5674719):

```
x <- c(753, 266, 49, 5)
m <- c(752.3, 267.1, 47.4, 6.2)
chisq.test(x, p=m/sum(m))
```

which gives me

```
  Chi-squared test for given probabilities

 data:  x
 X-squared = 0.2914, df = 3, p-value = 0.962
```

i.e. close but still different from 95% in the table.

For the last row in the table we get:

```
x <- c(444, 252, 59, 1)
m <- c(461.6, 227.7, 56.2, 10.5)
chisq.test(x, p=m/sum(m))

 Chi-squared test for given probabilities

 data:  x
 X-squared = 12, df = 3, p-value = 0.00739
```

Comment: Presumably Feller (or an assistant) was just using published tables and not even interpolating. It's a small historical puzzle of which tables were being used (e.g. Fisher and Yates?) and (depending on taste) a slightly amusing question of checking the results given and of seeing whether there are gross errors. Now as you exemplify we can get P-values directly but otherwise what is the precise goal of your question?

Comment: @NickCox If Feller had R would he put values from R I got into the table 5? Am I using chisq.test correctly?

Comment: Now that's a different question. Using quite different software I too get a chi-square test statistic of 0.2914 and  $P =$  0.962 for the first calculation, so I guess you are using R correctly, which isn't always on-topic here.

Comment: Using the *raw* data (which, being counts, are exact) and the posted mean of $ 0.35508$ (which has 5 significant figures) I obtain a chi-squared statistic of $0.27245$ with a p-value of $0.96513$ (with 3 df), which is all the precision the information is able to support.  But scanning the table shows Feller was posting p-values only to the nearest $0.05.$  It's unrealistic to suppose that 11 experimental chi-squared statistics would all be exactly multiples of $0.05$ anyway.

Comment: @whuber That's the answer - I like it a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I cannot reproduce the rightmost column in the table.**

It is evident that each row summarizes a table of counts by giving the frequencies $f_i$ of 0, 1, 2, and 3 or more, of which there are $N$ altogether.  It uses Maximum Likelihood to fit a Poisson distribution to these frequencies: the Poisson parameter estimates are the numbers $\lambda$ in the $Np(k;\lambda)$ expressions at the left and the corresponding expected frequencies $e_i$ appear to its right, beneath the data.  One would therefore suppose the "$\chi^2$ levels" at the right are upper tail areas of the chi-squared(df=3) statistics $\chi^2=\sum (f_i-e_i)^2/e_i,$ *aka* p-values.

Here is an accurately computed rendition of part of the table, as printed in `R` (with suitable rounding):

```
    lambda    0   1  2  >2    N   chi.sq     p
--  ------  --- --- --  -- ----  ------- -----
1  0.35322  753 266 49   5 1073  0.27030 0.966
2  0.45455  434 195 44   9  682  0.27970 0.964
3  0.27717  280  75 12   1  368  0.23118 0.972
4  0.11808 2278 273 15   0 2566  0.74954 0.861
5  0.25296  593 143 20   3  759  1.34312 0.719
6  0.21059  639 141 13   0  793  1.42313 0.700
7  0.28631  359 109 13   1  482  0.70899 0.871
8  0.33572  493 176 26   2  697  1.25717 0.739
9  0.39867  793 339 62   5 1199  3.33269 0.343
10 0.40430  579 254 47   3  883  3.70138 0.296
11 0.49339  444 252 59   1  756 11.99290 0.007
```

I checked the first and last p-value by invoking `chisq.test` as shown in the question: mine agree with it exactly, indicating I am using the correct degrees of freedom, etc.

**Some of the p-values are nowhere close to those in the original table,** even accounting for the evident reporting to the nearest 5% in the original.  Because the columns of p-values are qualitatively similar, tending to decrease down the table, *I suspect erroneous computation of the p-values in the original.*  Perhaps a crude approximation was used.

This is the `R` code I used.

```
#
# Negative log likelihood.
#
ll <- function(theta, x) {
  lambda <- exp(theta)
  n <- length(x) - 2
  -sum(c(dpois(0:n, lambda, log=TRUE), ppois(n, lambda, lower.tail=FALSE, log.p=TRUE)) * x)
}
X <- do.call(rbind, args=lapply(list( c(753, 266, 49, 5),
                                      c(434, 195, 44, 9),
                                      c(280, 75, 12, 1),
                                      c(2278, 273, 15, 0),
                                      c(593, 143, 20, 3),
                                      c(639, 141, 13, 0),
                                      c(359,109,13,1),
                                      c(493,176,26,2),
                                      c(793,339,62,5),
                                      c(579, 254, 47, 3),
                                      c(444,252, 59, 1)
), function(x) {
  names(x) <- as.character(seq.int(x)-1)
  names(x)[length(x)] <- paste0(">", length(x)-2)
  fit <- nlm(ll, log(sum(x * seq.int(x)) / sum(x) - 1), x=x)
  lambda <- exp(fit$estimate)
  N <- sum(x)
  e <- c(dpois(0:(length(x)-2), lambda), ppois(length(x)-2, lambda, lower.tail=FALSE)) * N
  chi.sq <- sum((x-e)^2/e)
  p.value <- pchisq(chi.sq, length(x) - 1, lower.tail=FALSE)
  data.frame(lambda=round(lambda, 5), as.list(x), N=sum(x), 
             chi.sq=round(chi.sq, 5), p=round(p.value, 3))
}))
print(X)
```